# Why do base64/openssl use a padding character of 'K' instead of '='

Tags: base64

Ive noticed that php `base64_encode` uses '=' as a padding character. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding) the different types use either '=' or none. However the CLI `base64` command as well as `openssl enc -base64` use 'K' as the padding. I am looking for information as to why and what implementations they use.

```
echo base64_encode('hello'); // aGVsbG8=
echo hello | base64 -i - // aGVsbG8K
openssl enc -base64 <<< hello   // aGVsbG8K
```

Comment: Did you find anything regarding this?

Comment: @DmytroI. I have not. I have found loads of info on openssl padding schemes but no answer to this. Even examples from openssl I found suggest it can uses '='. Stumped.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`K` is **not padding character**. It is a result of the newline which is added by the shell commands.

```
echo hello | openssl enc -base64 # aGVsbG8K
echo -n hello | openssl enc -base64 # aGVsbG8=
```

---

UPDATE:

#### Technical explanation

Base64 converts the provided **bitstream to 6-bit-chunks** instead of 8-bit chunks. Then a [special table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table) (other than the [ascii table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters)) with **64 printable-only characters** (thus the encoding name),  is used to **convert** these **6-bit chunks to characters**:

Let's see it in practice. (`print-bits` and `print-b64-bits` are imaginary commands )

**With newline:**

```sh
echo hello | print-bits

# 01101000 (h) 01100101 (e) 01101100 (l) 01101100 (l) 01101111 (o) 00001010 (\n)

echo hello | print-b64-bits

# 011010 (a) 000110 (G) 010101 (V) 101100 (s) 011011 (b) 000110 (G) 111100 (8) 001010 (K)
```

**No newline:**

```sh
echo -n hello | print-bits

# 01101000 (h) 01100101 (e) 01101100 (l) 01101100 (l) 01101111 (o)

echo -n hello | print-b64-bits

# 011010 (a) 000110 (G) 010101 (V) 101100 (s) 011011 (b) 000110 (G) 111100 (8)
```

In the latter case the output characters are 7. A **`=` char needs to be appended to make them 8 (a product of 4)**.

> Note: A **newline at the end is not always converted to `K`**. It **could be `o` or `g`**. This depends on the number of input bytes. Consider the case below:

```sh
echo helllo | print-bits

# 01101000 (h) 01100101 (e) 01101100 (l) 01101100 (l) 01101100 (l) 01101111 (o) 00001010 (\n)

echo helllo | print-b64-bits

# 011010 (a) 000110 (G) 010101 (V) 101100 (s) 011011 (b) 000110 (G) 110001 (x) 101111 (v) 000010 (C) 10 (g)
```

In the case above the **last 2 bits** will first be **padded with zeros**, then conversion to printable characters will follow. The **last output character is now `g`**.

And since the output characters are 10, two `=` need to be added to make them 12 (product of 4).

Comment: Thanks for answer! May I ask you to explain a technical details, how this happens? I mean how `=` become replaced with `K` and how `\n` affect this

Comment: @CAMOBAP `=` is the padding character for making the output characters a product of 4 (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Privacy-enhanced_mail). `echo hello` prints (by default) a newline character at the end, which is translated to K character after encoding. In this case no padding is performed since the output characters are 8 (2*4). If `-n` flag is used in echo, the newline is skipped. In such a case the output characters are 7, and any missing characters are padded with `=`.